# Samba Share Not Writable (Linux)

Tags: centos, centos7, samba

I am currently running a fresh install of CentOS 7 (64-bit). This machine isn't used for anything except for storage via Samba. However, for some strange reason, I can't see to get the share to be writable through windows. With the drive mapped, I can read the file lists and browse (even accessing files), but I cannot write any new files.

The steps that I took was to install samba via yum. I added a system user, bdawson, and then added that same user as a Samba user. I then logged in as that user and make a directory called storage (path being /home/bdawson/Storage).

I then edited my Samba config and added the following:

```
[Storage]
valid users = bdawson,@bdawson
path = /home/bdawson/Storage
write list = bdawson,@bdawson
```

/home/bdawson was chown -R'd to be owned by bdawson:bdawson. File permissions are set to 0755 for both /home/bdawson and /home/bdawson/Storage.

At this point, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong that is preventing me from being able to write. This same configuration worked just fine on a different machine, so I'm at a complete loss. (Side note: Samba logs aren't showing any issues and watching the Samba connections via Webmin does show that I am connecting and reading from the share, but attempts to write to it fail saying I need permission.)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I discovered this was due to a missing SELinux label. This was not an issue with my Ubuntu share, since Ubuntu doesn't use SELinux.